# Positive root of a sparse polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

Given $a, b, c > 0$, is it possible to compute the real positive root of the following sparse polynomial of degree $n \geq 2$?

$$P(x) = ax^n - bx + c$$

Comment: The question, I think, is precisely whether the sparsity - the fact that all coefficients except those in $x^n,x^1,x^0$ are $0$ - can be exploited to find a closed-form solution. Merely pointing at the fact that closed-form solutions do not exist for *general* polynomials of degree greater than 4 does not answer the question.

Comment: Does this polynomial have any positive roots?  By Descartes rule of signs, there are either $0$ or $2$ positive roots.  However, if $c$ is sufficiently large, then there are no roots.

Comment: Roots for this specific form of polynomials can be expressed in terms of [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical) which can be broken up as a finite series of generalized hypergeometric functions. However, I have doubt this "closed form" has any practical uses.

Comment: @Wouter I thought a sparse polynomial is one which when squared has the same or less terms than it started with

Answer (score 3):

Caveat: In the given setup, it is possible for the polynomial to have no real roots (when $c$ is sufficiently large).  Here, I am assuming that this polynomial has a root.  To check this, we can plug in the minimum from the derivative and check the sign of $f$ at that point.

It depends on what you mean by "compute."  Do you want a closed-form form of the roots?  Do you want to approximate the roots?  For sparse systems, you can sometimes get something out of the Newton polytope, but I'll use a more elementary approach.

First, consider the derivative of $f$.
$$
f'(x)=nax^{n-1}-b.
$$
We can easily see that this has a zero at
$$
x=\left(\frac{b}{na}\right)^{\frac{1}{n-1}}.
$$
This is a minimum of the polynomial and the value of the function of this point must be negative (if the polynomial has any roots - note that in your setup, the polynomial might not have any roots if $c$ is too large).

On the other hand, when $ax^n-bx=0$, the function is positive.  In other words, when 
$$
x=\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{n-1}},
$$
the function is equal to $c$.

Therefore, the root of interest is within the interval
$$
\left[\left(\frac{b}{na}\right)^{\frac{1}{n-1}},\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{n-1}}\right].
$$
For $n$ large with respect to $\frac{b}{a}$, this is a small interval.

Comment: You development is very hepful. Thank you so much.
Unfortunatly for me, n is very small in my case. Less thant 10 and I am not use that b/a is too small.

Comment: Perhaps if you include additional details in your question, we can find a more precise answer that helps you.

Comment: Ok 
I want to estimate a model and there is an accidental paremeter issue because it is a non linear model with fixed effects. To solve the problem I showed that the foc of the fixed effects can be expressed as this polynomial. So if I can compute the roots of the polynomial, I could replace the fixed effect by its expression (which is the root of this polynomial). I could get a concentrated likelihood that will not depend on fixed effects.