# Roots of sparse "quadratic-like" polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, factoring, roots-of-unity

So I know about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787275/positive-root-of-a-sparse-polynomial) and I've seen [papers like this](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/62920306.pdf) [and this](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2018/130/download/).  But the former isn't exactly what I want and the latter two papers are too deep and I'm lazy and I wanna quick-and-easy answer and I'm sure you legitimate mathematicians are happy to supply this lazy electrical engineer with a quick-and-easy answer, right?

So, in general, an $N$th-order polynomial with real coefficients is:

$$ f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n \, z^n \qquad \qquad \text{where }N\in\mathbb{Z}\ge0,\ a_n\in\mathbb{R},\ z\in\mathbb{C}$$

Now, consider this simple quadratic:

$$\begin{align}
 w^2 + bw + c &= w^2 (1 + bw^{-1} + cw^{-2})\\
&= (w-r_1)(w-r_2) \\
\end{align}$$

again $b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $w,r_1,r_2\in\mathbb{C}$ .  We know that

$$\begin{align}
 r_1 &= -\tfrac{b}{2} + \sqrt{\left(\tfrac{b}{2}\right)^2 - c} \\
 r_2 &= -\tfrac{b}{2} - \sqrt{\left(\tfrac{b}{2}\right)^2 - c} \\
\end{align}$$

if $b^2 \ge 4c$ and

$$\begin{align}
 r_1 &= -\tfrac{b}{2} + i\sqrt{c - \left(\tfrac{b}{2}\right)^2} \\
 r_2 &= -\tfrac{b}{2} - i\sqrt{c - \left(\tfrac{b}{2}\right)^2} \\
\end{align}$$

if $b^2 < 4c$

In the latter complex-conjugate case, we know that

$$ |r_1| = |r_2| = c $$

which is both simple and handy.

Now, whether the roots are real or complex-conjugate, suppose we have chosen $b$ and $c$ so that both

$$\begin{align}
 |r_1| &< 1 \\
 |r_2| &< 1 \\
\end{align}$$

Fine, now let's return to the sparse polynomial $f(z)$.  Suppose $N$ is even and **all** coefficients $a_n$ are zero except:

$$\begin{align}
 a_0 &= 1 \\
 a_{N/2} &= b \\
  a_N &= c \\
\end{align}$$

What are the roots of $f(z)$?  Suppose $N$ is pretty big (and even), say $N\approx 1000$.  If I can guarantee that $b$ and $c$ are chosen to insure that $|r_1|$ and $|r_2|$ are less than $1$, can I rely on all $N$ roots of $f(z)$ also being less than $1$?

I think that I can.  I've been fiddling with the substitution of

$$ w = z^{N/2} $$

and I know about the Nth-roots-of-unity, but am I guaranteed that all of the roots of the $N$th-order polynomial have magnitude less than $1$?

Comment: I guess if $|w|<1$, we know that $\big| z^{N/2} \big| < 1$ and $|z|<1^{2/N}$ and $|z|<1$.  So, although I dunno all $N$ roots of $f(z)$, I think I can say they are all inside the unit circle and that is the most important thing.  (But I would like to know what the values of the roots are, anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have the equation:
$$cz^{2n}+bz^n+1 = 0$$, 
where it's guaranteed that $z^n_{1,2}$ have modulus less than $1?$
If this is the case, then your intuition is correct because if:
$$|z^n| = |z|^n = |\omega| <1,$$
it must necessarily follow that: 
$$|z|<1$$
since $|z|$ is a positive real number.

Comment: or, at least a non-negative real number.